# spring batch integration with JPA

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, integration

I am new to spring batch and spring JPA. I was trying to read and write some records into DB with batch and JPA.

I am getting an error saying "Not a managed type: class Area"
Error creating bean with name 'areaRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class Area

Below are the code snippets:

BatchConfiguration.java:

```
 @Bean
  @StepScope
  public FlatFileItemReader<Area> reader(
      @Value("#{stepExecutionContext[fromId]}") final String fromId,
      @Value("#{stepExecutionContext[toId]}") final String toId,
      @Value("#{stepExecutionContext[name]}") final String name) {
    FlatFileItemReader<Area> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    try{

      reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("load_area.txt"));    
      reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Area>() {{
        setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{

           setNames(new String[]{"stateCode","areaCode","areaName"});

        }});      
        setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Area>() {{
          setTargetType(Area.class);
        }});
      }});
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return reader;
  }

    @Bean 
  @StepScope
  public ItemWriter<Area> slaveWriter(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[fromId]}") final String fromId,
      @Value("#{stepExecutionContext[toId]}") final String toId)  {
    return new AreaWriter();
  }
```

AreaWriter.java

```
public class AreaWriter implements ItemWriter<Area> {
  @Autowired
  AreaRepository areaRepository;

  @Override
  public void write(List<? extends Area> items)  {      
      for(Area user:items)
      {   
      areaRepository.save(user);
      }

  }
}



AreaRepository.java
@Repository
public interface AreaRepository extends CrudRepository<Area,Integer> {
}
```

Comment: Is Area class defined as @Entity? You will find tutorial at https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: Yes. Area is defined as Entity

Comment: Can you paste complete stacktrace and where you have configured Database configuration

Comment: I found what was wrong. Basically there are 2 main springbootapplications that were getting triggered. I removed one which is not needed.             
       Now I get could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null];                 ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("AREA"."STATE_CODE")

Comment: I  got it. I figured out there was null passed.